# Receiving events in Applescript-Objective C Scripting Bridge

Tags: objective-c, xcode, applescript, message, scripting-bridge

I'm attempting to write a program in Objective C that plays a notification when a message is received, using the Scripting Bridge. I've managed to set up the compilation and linked the libraries correctly; I can use all the functions in the 'messages.h' file generated by Scripting Bridge. However, this does not include the ability to receive messages. In Applescript, this is handled by the 'Message Event Handler Suite', but this doesn't seem to have directly carried over through the Scripting Bridge.There don't seem to be any generated functions that correspond to the specific Applescript event handling for messages. How can I receive events and messages directed at the messages application, in an Objective C program?

---

Edit: I'm not sure if this helps at all, but in the Messages.h file, the MessagesApplication class seems to use the MessagesSuite category.

```
@interface MessagesApplication (MessagesSuite)
```

I have not been able to find any documentation or information about this category, so I have no idea if its actually related to the Message Event Handler Suite in Applescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't receive Apple Events which belong to another application.

Comment: I don't think this is an "apple event belonging to another application"; it's a defined "event handler" in the scripting dictionary, which suggests there's a way to handle it.

Comment: So if want to send a Apple event to another application like "AXRaise", it not allowed unless I ask System Events app?

Comment: Actually in this case you are sending the AXRaise event to a process of System Events rather than to *another application* itself.